# Struggling to make a simple box

Tags: html, css

I'm new to webdev using html/css. Starting to learn, and I want to create a really simple thing.

**Basically a responsive fixed box that never touches the viewport by 20px.**

If you change the screen size, the box will always have a 20px margin, top, sides and bottom. I don't want scrolling at all!
Then at the center, I want to place a .gif that is about 40em that scales according to screen size.

My problems until now, is that I can't make that box at all, I've tried dozens and dozens of different solutions I've lost track of which ones, I've got 30 tabs opened with tutorials but none solve my problem.

Every try there is always a scrollbar, or the box has margins on top/left, but not bottom/right, or the gif is centered horizontally but not vertically, or there are margins but I can't control size of them....

Is this so hard? It would be awesome to have some directions, thank you!

This is what I currently have, but it's just one of the dozens of my failed attempts. (i didn't include the .gif)

```css
body {
  background: #f0e8e6;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

div {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  position: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: do you use a css reset? do you use box-sizing property?

Comment: i'm sorry, what is CSS Reset? I've used box-resizing property at a point yes

Comment: the scrollbar appears because your div is width 90vw + padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach:

```css
/* Using CSS custom properties to define
   the known, repeated measurement: */
:root {
  --margin: 20px;
}

/* setting the elements to all use the
   same box-sizing method, use the same
   font, margin and padding: */
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 1rem / 1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /* removed the properties that don't apply
     in the demo; using a background-color
     to visualise the sizing and layout: */
  background-color: white;
}

div {
  /* display: flex allows us to more easily
     position the contents
     vertically/horizontally:  */
  display: flex;
  /* using the calc function to calculate the
     space left over from subtracting 2 * 20px
     from 100vw (viewport-width units) to
     calculate the width, and from 100vw
     (viewport-height units)  to get the height: */
  width: calc(100vw - 2 * var(--margin));
  height: calc(100vh - 2 * var(--margin));
  /* applying the margin around the <div>: */
  margin: var(--margin);
  /* to easily visualise the layout: */
  background-color: red;
}

div img {
  /* to easily position the <img> in the
     horizontal and vertical centre: */
  margin: auto;
  /* setting the width leaves the browser
     to set the height appropriately to
     maintain the aspect-ratio: */
  width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.gif/09f/fff" alt="Placeholder gif">
</div>
```

References:

- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`font` short-hand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [Values and Units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).

Comment: Unless they leave a comment explaining their decision, I have to assume that somebody felt the answer wasn't useful for some reason. If it's of any use to others, over time, then it may attract votes in the future (or comments explaining why it's not a good answer).

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit of an odd way to go about it, but honestly I really enjoy this method as it has very easy to understand logic behind it. Apply the margin to the parent element via padding, not the child element.

```css
body {
  background: #f0e8e6;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Firstly, you need to remove the default padding/margin inbuilt into the `body`. Once you do that, you add the padding to the body - this gives the 20px margin. Finally, you need to ensure that the body spans the width of the page, and the div spans the width of the body. This is achieved by their respective width/height properties.

A key property here is `box-sizing`. This honestly should be the default, but essentially it stops the container from growing when adding padding. If this wasn't here, the body will overflow the page.

---

To add the image in the center, you should be using `flex`. It's quite a big topic, but it works perfectly for these situations. Learn more about flex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), but for now below in an example. Note the `align-items` and `justify-content` properties, these are what align the image vertically and horizontally.

```css
body {
  background: #f0e8e6;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>loiz</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css" media=”screen” />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/O"/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Note that the `top` and `left` css attributes only apply to elements with `absolute` or `fixed` positioning (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)).

Also, `position: center` is not a valid value. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for valid values.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use media queries for making it responsive for other devices , while provide a padding of 2% to the outermost div and then give and then place your gif in that div and provide that gif a padding also and you will get your required result

Comment: I don't really understand what media queries are yet.

I'm more worried about creating a responsive box first before placing the .gif. How would that translate into code? what properties should I use for the <body> and <div> ?

I guess <body> = background and total viewport (no scrolling)´

<div> = the box with 20px margin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea of how to accomplish this:

```css
body {
  background: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: calc(100vw - 40px);
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  background: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 40vw;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/10262654/pexels-photo-10262654.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"/>
   
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked really well, and it's really simple. This is the final result https://loiz.xyz/ . I think I get how it is working, But if you could just explain how it is different from what I was doing, it would be great, so that I could replicate it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

There are some default padding and margin on body tag. You need to reset them first. Also html tag is not full height by default as well. You also need to make them fullscreen by adding `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`

And then you can resize your div correctly. You can use calc method in css. In your case; `width: calc(100% - 240px)` 240px is 200px padding (100px each) for both sides and 40px margin (20px each).

To center gif for you can use flex features rather than using text-align etc.

```css
:root {
    --margin:  20px;
    --padding:  100px;
}
body, html {
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:  0;
    padding:  0;
}
body {
  background: #f0e8e6;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

div {
  width: calc(100% - (var(--margin) * 2) - (var(--padding) * 2));
  height: calc(100% - (var(--margin) * 2) - (var(--padding) * 2));
  padding:  var(--padding);
  background: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display:  flex;
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
  left: var(--margin);
  top:  var(--margin);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/WXZ5DqIOhQrxtkcszN/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47yzd9cgsu3pzebujrmdl3od4erxhdtwozizzjx2nc&amp;rid=giphy.gif&amp;ct=g" alt="Hell Yeah Snl GIF by Saturday Night Live" style="width: 500px; height: 280px; ">
</div>
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You're totally right. I'm just updating my answer.

Comment: This is a really good answer. I am now exploring the Flex features.